# Volume of a revolution for an ellipse?

Tags: calculus, volume

How do you even integrate an ellipse? The question is...

Rotating the ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ about the $x$-axis generates an ellipsoid. Compute its volume. The way i know how to rotate a function around the $x$ axis is by multiplying the integrand of $f(x)^2$ by $\pi$

$$\text{volume} = \pi \int f(x)^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume of revolution of a curve about the x-axis is calculated by

$$V= \int A(x)\,dx $$

where $A(x)$ is the cross sectional area

$$A(x)= \pi y^2$$

$$dV=\pi y^2\,dx$$
substituting $y^2=b^2(1-{x^2\over a^2})$ we get,

$$V=\int_{-a}^{a} \pi b^2(1-{x^2\over a^2})dx$$

On integrating we get 
$$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi ab^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{b^2}=1.$

My method is to do it in a spherical polar coordinate.
We define $x=ar\sin\theta\cos\varphi, y=br\sin\theta\sin\varphi, z=br\cos\theta$,
then $\text{d}V=\text{d}x\text{d}y\text{d}z=ab^2 r^2\sin\theta\text{d}r\text{d}\theta\text{d}\varphi$.
 The volume
\begin{align}
V = \iiint\text{d}V 
  = \int^1_0r^2\text{d}r\int^{2\pi}_0\text{d}\varphi\int^\pi_0ab^2\sin\theta \text{d}\theta
  = \frac{4ab^2\pi}{3}.
\end{align}

Comment: Your method is fine but you should be getting the volume as $\frac{4}{3}\pi ab^2$.

Comment: @Clock Slave I just check it in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid, I think the answer is $\frac{4}{3}ab\pi$. And my Jacobian here is correct.

Comment: I checked the wiki link. The volume they have given there is $\frac{4}{3}\pi abc$ and since the ellipse has been rotated   around x axis the value of c is equal to b. And thats when I realised that your equation should've been $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+{z^2 \over b^2}=1$